# How do I make a function execute if a property of an object is changed in LUA?

Tags: function, lua

So I want a function to be used once a change in a property is detected. How do I do that

Comment: Please write a code as example to explain what you want (how it might look like).

Comment: This site discusses property accessors: http://lua-users.org/wiki/ObjectProperties

Comment: [`__newindex`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#:~:text=__newindex)?

Comment: See https://www.lua.org/pil/13.4.4.html

Comment: You can copy [this code](https://github.com/DarkWiiPlayer/restia/blob/master/restia/accessors.lua) and see how far it takes you

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using metamethods `__index` and `__newindex`, but with some limitations. You need to use proxy table, i.e. result table will not be the same as observed table, as metamethod `__newindex` is called only if the table does not contain the key.

If you need to observe nested table properties, you must create recursive proxy table and modify it dinamically.

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fengari-web@0.1.4/dist/fengari-web.js"></script>

<script type="application/lua">

function observable(data, callback)
  return setmetatable({}, {
    __index = data,
    __newindex = function(self, n, v)
      local oldv = data[n]
      if v ~= oldv then
        data[n] = v
        callback(n, v, oldv)
      end
    end
  })
end


local my_object = { test1 = 'value1' }
my_object = observable(my_object,
  function(key,value,oldvalue)
    print('key='..key
          ..', value='..tostring(value)
          ..', oldvalue='..tostring(oldvalue))
    end)

my_object.test1 = 1
my_object.test2 = 2
my_object.test1 = 'othervalue'
my_object.test2 = nil

</script>
```